# How to manage user accounts in Azure Api management service?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management, user-management

In Azure portal, i wanted to create multiple useraccounts and then track those useraccounts for the data usage in Azure API management service. I can able to create the useraccounts but inorder to know how much data is used by those users for particular API, how can i get that metrics?

Comment: Also how to give access to the API`s in azure api management service to those useraccounts?

Answer (score 2):

API Management has 2 portals and 2 types of users.  The Azure Portal is used for API Managers (think users who publish APIs, operations, manage policy, etc.).  The Developer Portal is used by developers who are using (think customers) of your API.   In order to use an API the user/customer has to register with the Developer Portal and get a Subscription to a given API and the associated key.   So you have to authenticate them.

The Developer Portal supports different authentication mechanisms including Azure AD.  So if you plan to use Azure AD for your authentication for both portals you will need to configure it accordingly.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-aad

fwiw - by default the Developer portal provides a form based authentication for developers

Metric wise once a developer is registered you will be able to report on their activity through API Management.

Comment: To extend this answer. Users are either register themselves through Developer portal. Or you as owner of APIM service can invite/register users from Azure Portal. Look for Users item in left side menu of APIM service.